# Setting Variables to be Recognized by Other Methods

Tags: java, variables, scope

this is my first post, and I am very new to programming (teaching myself).  Please forgive me if my terminology is not exactly up to par or I make any other faux pas.  I am trying to write a program that uses two classes in order to take a user input and use that input to draw a simple rectangle on the screen.  I have gotten everything to work, but I cannot get the user generated content to be recognized.  I have defined an 'x' variable, and the user inputs a value for that, but that value gets passed through as '0' every time.  The user is prompted to put in an integer value that will be used as the 'x' value when creating a fillrectangle.  When run, though, the x value is always '0'.  Somehow the variable 'x' is not getting changed to the user inputted value.

Below is my code, as poor as it might be.  Hopefully someone can give me a couple ideas.

MAIN CLASS

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class first {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        second p = new second();
        p.setValues();
        p.getX();
        JFrame j = new JFrame("New Rectangle");
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        second t = new second();
        j.add(t);
        j.setSize(500,500);
        j.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

SECOND CLASS

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class second extends JPanel{
     int x;

    public void setValues()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the X value");
        x = s.nextInt();

    }



    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        System.out.println(x);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, 20, 50, 50);

    }
}
```

Comment: Need the code for second.getX().

Comment: @user2714543 The code's not too bad actually. The one thing I see is that by convention, class names should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you collect the information using the object referenced by the variable named `p`, but you then draw to the screen with the object referenced by the variable `t`. Variables are not shared between classes unless they are static - take a look at this documentation for more information.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

One way to help visualize this is to think of a Class as just a blueprint. You're describing what the data is going to look like, and how it's going to be worked with. When you're ready to build something from your blueprint, you use the `new` keyword. At that point, you have a new object, based on your description from the blueprint, i.e. the class file.

To use a real world example: if you have a blueprint for a certain type of house, and you and I both built our houses exactly to the spec of this blueprint, one could say that we have the same house. But in truth, we don't; if I have 20 cats and my house gets smelly, your house won't stink. Our floorplans are identical, but what is actually going on inside each of our houses is very different.

To make the code work, simply get rid of the `t` variable, and call `j.add(p);`

EDIT: Adding a little more detail. The reason that the value is always 0 is because Java chooses a default value for a primitive type when it is first initialized. In the case of integers, that default value is 0.

Comment: Thanks so much!  You are correct.  I was calling two different instances, so as soon as I made the drawing in the same instance as the inputting, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the x value is always 0 is because you are creating another instance of it when you say

```
second t = new second(); //Creates a new instance of x (another copy of x)
```

If you just do `System.out.print(p.x);` after `p.setValues()` you will get the correct value of x.

As far as your code, I do not quite understand the reason why p is there.  Just doing something like this should work:

```
    JFrame j = new JFrame("New Rectangle");
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   second t = new second();

   t.setValues();
   j.add(t);
   j.setSize(500, 500);
   j.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Yeah, this was what it was.  Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!